# "void type not allowed here"

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy creando un juego de dados orientado a objetos en Java. Donde tengo las clases: "Dado", "Jugador" y "MainActivity". Un dado es un número aleatorio del 1 al 6 mientras que un jugador tiene dos dados. Por último, el MainActivity se encargará de ejecutar la salida del juego.

```
public class Jugador {

//Atributos
private Dado dado1;
private Dado dado2;

 public Jugador() {

    dado1 = new Dado();
    dado2 = new Dado();

}

//Llamo a los daditos para que se ejecuten:

public void tirarDaditos() {
    
    dado1.getValor();
    dado2.getValor();
```

El problema está en cuando quiero llamarlos desde MainActivity, dice que al ser una función Void no puedo hacer tal:

```
    if (jugador1.tirarDaditos() == 6) {
        
        System.out.println("Ga");
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería una adaptación de la respuesta de @Jorgesys, basada en tus comentarios.

en Jugador:

```
public int[] tirarDaditos() { 
    int valorDados[] = { dado1.getValor(), dado2.getValor() };   
    return valorDados;  
 }
```

y en MainActivity:

```
int sumaDados( Jugador jug ) {
    int valores[] = jug.tiraDaditos();
    return valores[ 0 ] + valores[ 1 ];
}

if( sumaDados( jugador1 ) == 6 ) {        
    System.out.println( "Ga" );        
}
```

El método **tirarDaditos** crea una array con los valores de los datos y lo devuelve.

En **MainActivity**, el método **sumarDados**, recibe como parámetro un objeto *Jugador*, crea un array que inicializa invocando con el jugador recibido al método **tiraDaditos()**, y devuelve la suma de los valores que contiene.
El **if** invoca al método **sumaDados**, pasandole como parámetro un jugador, compara el valor que este devuelve con "6", y si hay coincidencia, ejecuta el código que contiene.

PD: Puedes declarar **int valores[]** fuera del método **sumaDados** e instanciarlo dentro, si necesitas usar los valores para otra cosa.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error indica:

> "tipo void no es permitido aquí"

Recuerda que palabra reservada `void` se utiliza en los métodos para indicar que no se retornara nada, entonces en este punto estás realizando una comparación de un valor que retornará `.tirarDaditos()` lo cual es incorrecto, ya que no se podría si defines un valor de retorno `void` :

```
 if (jugador1.tirarDaditos() == 6) {
```

En realidad tu método `tirarDaditos()` debería retornar algún valor, debería ser algo similar a:

```
public class Jugador {

//Atributos
private Dado dado1;
private Dado dado2;

 public Jugador() {

    dado1 = new Dado();
    dado2 = new Dado();
    
 }

 public int tirarDaditos() {    
    return dado1.getValor() + dado2.getValor(); //regresa la suma de valores
 }
 
}
```

Comment: El problema es que ya tengo esa función llamada getSuma(), pero necesito saber el valor de cada dado para mostrarlo desde el MainActivity. Es decir, necesito que la clase Jugador haga de pasillo para Dado. Jugador debe saber el valor de cada dado cual ha sido generado con un número aleatorio al igual que Main. Por lo que no sé muy bien como hacer eso @Jorgesys

Comment: ok, deseas saber los valores de dado1 y dado2 desde una instancia de Jugador, agrega mejor toda tu clase Dado().

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estoy entendiendo de tu pregunta y el comentario que le hiciste a @Jorgesys ...
Lo que puedes hacer es guardar el estado del `Dado`. Dado debería tener un atributo `valor` y operaciones para cambiar su valor (generar un random de 1 a 6) y leerlo.
Entonces `tirarDaditos` debería llamar a una operación del `Dado` (tirar o algun otro nombre) que debería setear el valor de cada dado. Posteriormente el jugador puede leer el valor del dado con un getter (`getValor()` o similar).

Adicionalmente deberías pensar si está bien que el jugador cree instancias de `Dado` o mejor que se creen fuera. ¿Los dados son del jugador o los puede compartir con otros?.